# Error : While installing dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘R6’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force the installation of the dependencies.

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies=TRUE)
```

If this still doesn't work, try installing the missing packages yourself, e.g.

```
install.packages("R6", dependencies=TRUE)
```